# Visual Studio 2012 debugger not running with my latest Javascript changes

Tags: debugging

I'm running my MVC 4 using Visual Studio 2012 in the debugger but it is not using my latest JavaScript changes.  when I used developer tools to view the source in both IE and Chrome I see the old code.
  I've tried:
1)  in IE 11 settings check for new version "every time I visit the webpage"
2)  cleaning the solution
3)  rebooting my machine
4)  going to:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files and only finding a "root" folder with virtually empty folders and  a few 1kb files
5)  deleted all my breakpoints

It seems after 24 hours or so the code changes are there.  Why is this happening and what else can I try to fix it?

JJ

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some form of caching issue. Try disabling your browser's caches, maybe even run it without debugging. It is hard to say exactly what might be going on without knowing your exact setup.

Hope this points you in the right direction, I have had similar issues with PHP code doing this.

Comment: I ran it without the VS debugger and then hooked it with the IE debugger and saw my new code changes.  That worked for about 5 tests but now even that is starting to show me old code again.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Does anyone have any other ideas?